# Idiomatic Analog to Ruby's `Object#tap` for Unix command Pipelines?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, unix, pipeline

Is there an idiomatic analog to Ruby's `Object#tap` for Unix command pipelines?

Use case: within a pipeline I want to execute a command for its side effects but return the input implicitly so as to not break the chaining of the pipeline. For example:

```
echo { 1, 2, 3 } |
  tr ' ' '\n' |
  sort |
  tap 'xargs echo' | # arbitrary code, but implicitly return the input
  uniq
```

I'm coming from Ruby, where I would do this:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ].
  sort.
  tap { |x| puts x }.
  uniq
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tee` command is similar; it writes its input to standard output as well as one or more files. If that file is a process substitution, you get the same effect, I believe.

```
echo 1 2 3 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | tee >( **code** ) | uniq
```

The code in the process substitution would read from its standard input, which should be the same thing that the call to `uniq` ends up seeing.

Comment: +1 for 'process substitution'. There goes the need for most of the /tmp files I've ever used.

Comment: And in case you just want to display to `stderr`, `... | tee /dev/stderr | ...`.